# How to use Accelerate framework outside of Mac

Tags: linux, xcode, macos, accelerate-framework

I am trying to compile and run code that uses the Accelerate Framework (it includes Accelerate/accelerate.h). I am doing this in Linux. I do not have a Mac, and I do not have Xcode. Is there anywhere I can go to download the source code for this library, or otherwise make this compile?

I have Googled this extensively, but have not found clear answers. Some sites suggest I need to download LAPACK and BLAS, but I don't know if this is sufficient.

Comment: The short answer is no.  You might be able to port the code to another high performance vector library, but given our question I suspect you would be better off finding a native implementation for Linux of whatever algorithm you wanted.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. The Accelerate framework is proprietary to Apple, and is only available for use with Mac OS X and iOS.

IO: BLAS and LAPACK make up a part of Accelerate.framework. This component is industry standard and indeed you can just download a version of BLAS and LAPACK from netlib.org and run that on linux.  If your application uses interfaces from the rest of Accelerate.framework (e.g. vDSP, vImage, vForce...) then you have more work to do.  Some similar functionality for these things can be found in FFTW, OpenCV, and Open-SAL, Intel MKL and Intel Performance Primitives, but the interfaces won't match and some of the features will be different / missing.